# external link to google map marker

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to make an external link that pulls up the info bubble of a marker and centers it.  I wanted to do it by referencing a div ID that I called clickaway, this is what I set up but can't seem to get it working:

```
<script>
  function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 4,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

    var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
        '<div id="siteNotice">'+
        '</div>'+
        '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>'+
        '<div id="bodyContent">'+
        '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
        'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the '+
        'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) '+
        'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km '+
        '(280&#160;mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major '+
        'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is '+
        'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the '+
        'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, '+
        'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World '+
        'Heritage Site.</p>'+
        '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?
 title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'+
        'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> '+
        '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>'+
        '</div>'+
        '</div>';

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });


    var name = '#clickaway';


    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Hello World!'
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(name, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });


  }


  function loadScript() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&' +
        'callback=initialize';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }

  window.onload = loadScript;
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you want to use `addDomListener` instead of `addListener`, since, as it's name says, can listen to the events for an object in the DOM. Check this [sample made](http://jsbin.com/afetot/1/edit) from your code, note that the CSS selector in your `name` variable is gone.

Comment: thanks a lot for the example and the help, I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work that way, the marker is a javascript object, it can't be referenced with an HTML id.   If you make the marker global, you can reference it in an HTML onclick function.

```
onclick="google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');"
```

[Another example with a clickable sidebar](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map2.html)

Comment: thanks a lot, it's always really helpful when people can explain exactly why something's wrong :)